# How to import Contacts from old Sony Ericsson C702 to Xperia X10?

Tags: contacts, sony-ericsson-xperia-x10, import

How can I import contacts from non-android phone?

Are there dedicated applications?

What I want to avoid is doubling contacts when moving them from old phone to SIM card and then to new phone.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you get your contacts from your old phone into GMail? Android syncs very nicely with GMail, so if you can do that you won't need to worry about copying to and from the SIM card.

Comment: Unfortunately this phone is too old to be capable of such sophisticated feature :)

Comment: Your phone doesn't need to be in any way sophisticated to do this. The Sony Ericsson PC Suite software mentioned below should allow you to download your contacts from your old phone to a PC. You should then have the option to export/save these as a CSV file. The Contacts section of GMail has an Import option where you can upload this CSV file, this should get all your Contacts into GMail and then they'll sync down to your new phone. See some other contact import questions like http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/467/how-do-i-transfer-my-phone-numbers-to-an-android-phone

Answer (score 2):

I have no prior experience with Sony Erricsson software, but I think their PC Suite solution (found [here](http://www.sonyericsson.com/cws/support/softwaredownloads/detailed/pccompanion/xperiax10?cc=gb&lc=en)) deals with the syncing of Contacts etc.

Answer (score 1):

I just succeeded in transferring all  my C702 contacts to Gmail via the Sony Ericsson C702 PC suite.  My new Samsung Galaxy S2 was updated with my contacts within a few minutes with no further measures, though I had logged into my Gmail account via the Samsung phone earlier.  I tried Bluetooth transfer from the C702 which didn't work, although I didn't try the X10 transfer route.

Answer (score 1):

You can use powerful and free software **MyPhoneExplorer** (from www.fjsoft.at). It works with all SonyEricsson Old phones and most Android phones (including X10). You can easily backup contacts from C702 to your PC and then import the contacts to your X10.

Comment: To all: **don't use this software**. It is free, yes, but it installs a ton of malware that is not so easy to delete (you'll need to remove several system tasks, stop/remove two or three system services, kill some processes and then physically delete malware executables/dlls). I spent about an hour removing all this stuff, yet I'm not sure that my system is completely clean now.

Comment: @sam.kozin: Thanks for the warning. I've used it years ago. It is a versatile software and probably the best software for handling  sony erricsson phones. I am going to install it in a sandbox (Sandboxie ) and use it.

Answer (score 0):

The X10 Phone Book application can import vCard-files.

I imported my Palm Centro contact list successfully using 1.6, but it failed in 2.1. I think the import facility in 2.1 is a lot pickier. I'm sure it'll import fine if I clean up the vCard file a bit. I've written to Sony Ericsson and complained as well.

Answer (score 0):

As a **last resort** you can use Bluetooth to send the contacts to the new phone. Just select all contacts and send them to the X10 (pair first) and then set the X10 to accept all incoming files from the C702. After all contacts have been sent (they're separate vCard files) go to the phone book and press `Menu -> More -> Import contacts -> Memory card` and select the contacts from your bluetooth folder. **Haven't tested** with SE phones but worked with Nokia->Samsung and Samsung->Samsung.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing it via bluetooth. In first place the PC-Companion for C702 is not the same version as for the Xperia, so you will have two installations. And when I've tried syncing through the sonyerricson online sync service (SynML) I've faced the problem that some number types ("mobile (privat)" and "mobile (work)") could be exported to the online service, but not imported back to the Xperia. They were missing on my Xperia. So make sure if "mobile (privat)" and "mobile (work)" numbers of your C702 are missing on your XPERIA. Seems that number types "mobile (privat)" and "mobile (work)" have problems being accepted on other phones. But when I did it via bluetooth, Android switched the number types correctly on the fly.